# how can I error handling alphabets and negative numbers?

Tags: c++

please help I need to block incoming alphabets and negative numbers 
like error handling or something 
here is the codes

```
{
printf("\nEnter number of Processes:");
scanf("%d", &n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)


{
    printf("\nEnter Process ID %d :",i+1);
    scanf("%d", &process[i]);
    printf("\nEnter Process Time %d:",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&ptime[i]);
}

for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(ptime[i]>ptime[j])
        {
            temp = ptime[i];
            ptime[i] = ptime[j];
            ptime[j] = temp;
            ptemp = process[i];
            process[i] = process[j];
            process[j] = ptemp;
        }
    }
}
    wtime[0]=0;
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    wtime[i]=wtime[i-1]+ptime[i-1];
    total=total+wtime[i];
}
avg=(float)total/n;
printf("\nProcess ID\t Process TIME\t Waiting TIME\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("    %d\t           %d\t          %d\n",  process[i],  ptime[i],  wtime[i]);
printf("\nTotal Waiting Time: %d \nAverage Waiting Time: %f", total, avg);
```

thanks in advance need to finish it hehehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way: check for errors and terminate if there are some errors.

```
// add #include <cstdlib> at the beginning of your code to use exit()

{
printf("\nEnter number of Processes:");
if(scanf("%d", &n)!=1 || n<0)exit(1);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)


{
    printf("\nEnter Process ID %d :",i+1);
    if(scanf("%d", &process[i])!=1 || process[i]<0)exit(1);
    printf("\nEnter Process Time %d:",i+1);
    if(scanf("%d",&ptime[i])!=1 || ptime[i]<0)exit(1);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To do all exiting by one `exit()`, using a flag is a good Idea.
In this way, it is easier to do other actions, such as printing error message.

```
// add #include <cstdlib> at the beginning of your code to use exit()

{
bool error_found = false;
printf("\nEnter number of Processes:");
if(scanf("%d", &n)!=1 || n<0)error_found = true;
else
{
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)


    {
        printf("\nEnter Process ID %d :",i+1);
        if(scanf("%d", &process[i])!=1 || process[i]<0){error_found = true; break;}
        printf("\nEnter Process Time %d:",i+1);
        if(scanf("%d",&ptime[i])!=1 || ptime[i]<0){error_found = true; break;}
    }
}
if (error_found) {
    // some error exists
    puts("MUST NOT ALPHABET OR NEGATIVE NUMBER!");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: if i want to add a message how can i do it?  example like MUST NOT ALPHABET OR NEGATIVE NUMBER!

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the input using a string type, then convert the string to what result you want. For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int processed_input;
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    stringstream ss(input);
    try {
        ss >> processed_input;
        if(processed_input < 0) throw "Negative number";
    } catch(exception &e) {
        cout << "Error : non-numeric characters inputted";
    } catch(const char* msg) {
        cout << "Error : " << msg << " inputted";
    }
    return 0;
}
```